# Is it possible to have 2D and 3D properties of the shader in Unity?

Tags: unity, shaders

In properties of standard objects there are both 2D and 3D properties, like this

[image]

On the other hand, in properties of a shader, [I can apparently specify](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Properties.html) only 1D and 4D properties. Is this true? Is the possiblity to specify 2D and 3D really omitted?

Comment: Anything you can put into a 2- or 3-component vector, you can put into a 4-component vector. Have you run into any particular difficulty making this work for a specific shader effect?

Comment: @DMGregory yes, I know I was just wondering, can I have 2 fields in a row in property editor; so I can't?

Comment: So you specifically want them to show up as 2 or 3 component in the editor, and it is fine if they are 4 component under the hood?

Comment: @WeckarE. if it is impossible directly, I would say it is fine as is; no reason to apply any efforts to hide developer params. I was just wondering.